# How can I fix the NoSuchMethodError from the Time4J Library?

Tags: java, javafx, nosuchmethod, time4j

I'm having throble with **NoSuchMethodError** in this line of my code:

```
    private CalendarPicker<PersianCalendar> calendarPicker = CalendarPicker.persianWithSystemDefaults();
```

It works fine when I run the project in intellij idea but the output jar file won't run.
I exported the project in eclipse and got this error in eclipse.

I used this libraries:

1 - time4j-core-4.38

2 - time4j-ui-5.5

3 - time4j-calendar-4.38.jar

4 - time4j-base-5.5.jar

**Full text of the error:**

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: net.time4j.scale.LeapSecondProvider: Provider net.time4j.scale.spi.DefaultLeapSecondProviderSPI could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at net.time4j.base.ResourceLoader$StdResourceLoader.services(ResourceLoader.java:463)
    at net.time4j.scale.LeapSeconds.<init>(LeapSeconds.java:201)
    at net.time4j.scale.LeapSeconds.<clinit>(LeapSeconds.java:179)
    at net.time4j.SystemClock.calibrate(SystemClock.java:474)
    at net.time4j.SystemClock.<clinit>(SystemClock.java:95)
    at net.time4j.ui.javafx.CalendarPicker.lambda$persianWithSystemDefaults$15(CalendarPicker.java:761)
    at net.time4j.ui.javafx.CalendarControl.<init>(CalendarControl.java:82)
    at net.time4j.ui.javafx.CalendarPicker.<init>(CalendarPicker.java:178)
    at net.time4j.ui.javafx.CalendarPicker.create(CalendarPicker.java:1110)
    at net.time4j.ui.javafx.CalendarPicker.persian(CalendarPicker.java:785)
    at net.time4j.ui.javafx.CalendarPicker.persianWithSystemDefaults(CalendarPicker.java:759)
    at HomeScreenController.<init>(HomeScreenController.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Main.start(Main.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.time4j.PlainDate.localFormatter(Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/time4j/format/ChronoPattern;)Lnet/time4j/format/TemporalFormatter;
    at net.time4j.scale.spi.DefaultLeapSecondProviderSPI.<init>(DefaultLeapSecondProviderSPI.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 44 more
Exception running application Main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `NoSuchMethodError` normally means you have a dependency difference between your compile time and runtime environments.

In effect, it's likely that you have either:
1. multiple different versions of the `net.time4j` JAR on your classpath
2. a different `net.time4j` JAR on your runtime classpath than was used during compile time.

Since the call hierarchy seems to suggest `net.time4j` itself is calling a method it doesn't know about, I suspect multiple JAR versions on the classpath.

This seems to be consistent with the JARs you're talking about using. You're mixing version `4.38` and version `5.5`. You should stick to using one version of all the libraries in the suite, as they will likely be designed to work together.

You're probably a bit confused because it seems that Time4J changed the packaging between the 4.x and 5.x versions, and `time4j-core` is probably now named `time4j-base`

There is a [tutorial page on the Time4J website](http://time4j.net/tutorial/overview.html) which seems to suggest you can simply remove your existing dependencies on `time4-core` and `time4j-calendar`.

Comment: Yes, the old v4.38-dependencies can just be removed in favor of time4j-base-5.5.jar (and time4j-ui-5.5 for the JavaFX-component). One small correction though: the new base-module (in v5.x) is replacing the old core-module AND the old calendar-module (in v4.38).

Answer (score 1):

I've had had the same Issue, with a mix of the different time4j - Versions, because of different sources found online.

So this was the NOT WORKING - POM.XML - Configuration leading to the problem:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.time4j/time4j-core -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>time4j-parent</artifactId>
          <version>5.5</version>
          <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>time4j-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.38</version>
       </dependency>      
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.time4j/time4j-base -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>time4j-base</artifactId>
           <version>5.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>time4j-i18n</artifactId>
           <version>4.38</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

SOLUTION: Update of the MAVEN - Repository. Maven was still using 4.38, eventough I've changed to 5.5 - a cleanup (purging) of the repository was necessary.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.time4j/time4j-base -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>time4j-base</artifactId>
           <version>5.5</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
               <archive>
                 <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                 </manifest>
               </archive>
             </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.1</version>
              <executions>
                 <execution>
                    <id>build-classpath</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                       <goal>build-classpath</goal>
                       <goal>purge-local-repository</goal>
                     </goals>
                   <configuration>
                    <!-- configure the plugin here -->
                   </configuration>
                 </execution>
              </executions>
           </plugin>           
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
```

Now it work's like a charm.